# .isGrounded is not working reliably

Tags: unity, c#

New to Unity and C#, though, I got the code from the [official doc page](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html) for Character Controller and thought that should work by default.

When pressing the Jump button here it doesn't always work. When checking if the player is grounded the variable `groundedPlayer` not always provides `true` when idle/not moving. Instead, the value is constantly changing between true and false.

Below is my current code which was modified a little:

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
  private CharacterController controller;
  private Vector3 playerVelocity;
  private bool groundedPlayer;
  private float jumpHeight = 1.0f;
  private float gravityValue = -9.81f;

  private void Start()
  {
    controller = gameObject.AddComponent<CharacterController>();
  }

  void Update()
  {
    groundedPlayer = controller.isGrounded;
    //this will constantly return both false and true while idle
    print(groundedPlayer + ", " + playerVelocity + ", " + gameObject.transform.position.y.ToString("f8"));
    if (groundedPlayer && playerVelocity.y < 0)
    {
      playerVelocity.y = 0f;
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && groundedPlayer)
    {
      playerVelocity.y += Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -3.0f * gravityValue);
    }

    playerVelocity.y += gravityValue * Time.deltaTime;

    controller.Move(playerVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
  }

}
```

It's just that I feel dumb since basic jumping is this difficult to implement for me. I feel like I'm missing something very obvious. I found 1 working solution for me which is implementing coyote time, but it looks like a workaround and might provide more glitches in the future. I also could try working on creating my own character controller, though that's a whole different field.

Anyone had this issue before? How did you fix it?

Comment: I note that you're applying a downward velocity to your character even when they're already grounded. Is it possible this is causing miniature rebounds?

Comment: @DMGregory 2 consecutive updates: `True, (0.0, -0.1, 0.0), 0,08000498` | `False, (0.0, -0.1, 0.0), 0,08000498`. Third one is Y-position. Also, it's 0.8 because Unity is applying colliding skin width, though from what I found online that shouldn't be a problem. I also altered the code a bit just for testing purposes, you can see the new version in the question.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the skin width of the controller?

Comment: @DMGregory absolutely no changes even when it's set to 1. Well, except that the object is now visually levitating.

Comment: I just tested. When I changed `playerVelocity.y = 0f;` to `playerVelocity.y = -0.5f;` it's now working perfectly. Apparently, the downforce vector was too small for it to detect collision. Now it's just weird that I have to add that 0.5 to every reverse vector as a workaround. @DMGregory thank you, I wouldn't have figured it out on my own.

Comment: Want to share your solution as an answer?

Comment: @Telion this is a common behavior for Character Controller. If your vertical velocity is 0, the `isGrounded` parameter is not reliably. You need to put a small negative value, so the collision is always happening.

Comment: @ArturNista yea, the issue was that it has to be somewhat big actually. I was trying `-0.1f` prior to asking here and it just wasn't enough, though my thought was that it's just not the case here, until now when I noticed that it's switching to true somewhere around -0.4.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the downforce vector was too small to make Unity recognize collision. I am not sure how big the vector has to be or if anything affects how big it has to be but in my case it is something around `-0.45f`. I've set the downforce vector to at least `-0.5f` when it first gets grounded and seems like it's working as intended now. The only issue is that I have to keep in mind that I have a fix of -0.5 now by default.

So `playerVelocity.y = 0f` changed to `playerVelocity.y = -0.5f;`:

```
  void Update()
  {    
    // jumping mechanic
    groundedPlayer = controller.isGrounded;
    if (groundedPlayer && playerVelocity.y < 0)
    {
      playerVelocity.y = collisionFixForce;
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && groundedPlayer)
    {
      playerVelocity.y += Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -3.0f * gravityValue + -collisionFixForce);
    }

    playerVelocity.y += gravityValue * Time.deltaTime;

    controller.Move(playerVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
  }
```